# Why is my app token inactive?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am using app token found here
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
under my newly created app(2nd line)

```
var graph = new facebook.GraphAPI(accessToken);
graph.getConnections('me', 'friends', print);

function print(error, data) {
  console.log(error ? error : data);
}
```

Why is it still throwing the error? What am I missing?

> An active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a User Token, not an App Token. There is no relation to any user with the App Token, you need to authorize a user with the `user_friends` permission to get his friends. Keep in mind that you will only get friends who authorized your App with `user_friends` too, for privacy reasons.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

You may find this article helpful for the authorization part: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

For non-restricted Pages, you can just use an App Token though: `https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/videos?limit=20&acce‌​ss_token=myappid|mys‌​ecret`

...of course you can also use the vanity name instead of the ID.

Comment: I think manually-build-a-login-flow comes closest to my requirement. Actually I don't need user data, maybe I am testing with wrong params. My usecase is to fetch videos from few pages inside webview of an android app without fb login. isn't the App token sufficient for non user specific data? And can I hardcode a fixed access token?

Comment: something like this `curl graph.facebook.com/v2.9/somechannelname/videos?limit=20&access_token=myappid|mysecret` but here I am getting error saying `{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"A3\/KBb7RFAb"}}`

Comment: for non-restricted pages you can use an app token. you cannot use "me", you need to use a page id. is "somechannelname" a page? i just tested it with another page and it does work.